# Python Request To Google Colab (Post) Return 405 Code Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to request and get results from my local python code to my google colab code but I'm getting a 405 error

**My local python code is below**

```
//my api.py code on google colab**
colab_url = 'https'
data = {'param': 'test'}
response = requests.post(colab_url, data=data)
```

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def process_request():
     param_value = request.form.get('param')

      if param_value == "test":
          return "1"
      else:
        return "0"

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

I'm printing the response from google colab to a txt file, unfortunately the response is as follows instead of 1 or 0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>405.</b> <ins>That is an error.</ins>


I tried to change the data types from my python code and it d
```

idn't work. I changed the request type, it still didn't work